# CoordinatorLayout isn't scrolling after nestedscrollview or recyclerview removing

Tags: android, android-layout, android-coordinatorlayout, android-nestedscrollview

When switching tabs I hide (view.removeAllViews() or INVISIBLE or GONE) the content of the old tab and show the content of the new tab.
The content (@+id/container) of each tab contains Nestedscrollview or Recyclerview.

1. When you open the form everything works fine.
2. After switching, the form scrolling does not work when you touch
   AppBarLayout
3. After scrolling for Nestedscrollview or Recyclerview, scrolling for
   AppBarLayout starts working.

I'm putting this in CoordinatorLayout:

> ```
> <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
>     android:id="@+id/app_bar"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_list_items"
>     android:background="@drawable/product_detail_background"
>     android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
>     app:theme="@style/ProductDetailsAppBar">
>
>     <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
>         android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar_layout"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:background="@drawable/product_detail_background"
>         android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
>         app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
>         app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
>         app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
>         app:scrimAnimationDuration="100">
>
>         <LinearLayout
>             android:id="@+id/ll_app_bar_content"
>             android:layout_width="match_parent"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dim_8"
>             android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
>             android:orientation="vertical"
>             app:layout_collapseMode="none">
>
>             ...
>
>         </LinearLayout>
>
>         <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
>             android:id="@+id/toolbar"
>             android:layout_width="match_parent"
>             android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
>             android:layout_gravity="top"
>             android:scrollbarFadeDuration="100"
>             app:layout_collapseMode="pin">
>
>            ...
>
>         </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
>
>     </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
>
>     <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
>         android:id="@+id/tl_product"
>         style="@style/TabLayout"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_list_items">
>
>        ...
>
>     </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
>
> </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
>
> <FrameLayout
>     android:id="@+id/container"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent"
>     android:background="@color/white"
>     app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
>
> <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu
>     android:id="@+id/fab_menu"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent"
>     android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
>     android:padding="@dimen/margin_fab"
>     app:menu_backgroundColor="@color/fab_transparent_background"
>     app:menu_colorNormal="@color/main_green"
>     app:menu_colorPressed="@color/main_green"
>     app:menu_icon="@drawable/ic_add">
>
>     ...
>
> </com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu>
> ```

Comment: `view.removeAllViews() or INVISIBLE or GONE` which is it, because removing all views removes them from the application, INVISIBLE just hides them but calculates their size for layout purposes, and gone leaves them in the application but their size is effectively `0,0` for layout purposes.

Comment: Yes, I know it. But I mean that with any method of view hiding, there are problems with scrolling.

Comment: So you have a built-in layout that malfunctions when you change the content of the layout? Are you rebuilding the whole screen after changing it so the new resizing is taking place? At any rate, from what I read it could be a problem in the [hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41361579/android-collapsing-toolbar-was-not-hiding-other-element-while-collapsed).